# Read a value from multiple text files and write all into another file

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files, fopen, overwrite

I have a list of sub-folders and each sub-folder has a text file name called `simass.txt`. From each of the `simass.txt` files I extract a `c{1}{2,3}` cell data (as done in the code below) and write it to a file name `features.txt` in sequential form in single column.

I am facing a problem where at the end I only have a single value in `features.txt`, which I believe is due to the values being overwritten. I'm supposed to have 1000 values in `features.txt` since I have 1000 sub-folders.

What am I doing wrong?

```
clc;    % Clear the command window.
workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
format long g;
format compact;
% Define a starting folder wherever you want
start_path = fullfile(matlabroot, 'D:\Tools\Parameter Generation\');
% Ask user to confirm or change.
topLevelFolder = uigetdir(start_path);
if topLevelFolder == 0
  return;
end
% Get list of all subfolders.
allSubFolders = genpath(topLevelFolder);
% Parse into a cell array.
remain = allSubFolders;
listOfFolderNames = {};
while true
[singleSubFolder, remain] = strtok(remain, ';');
if isempty(singleSubFolder)
    break;
    end
listOfFolderNames = [listOfFolderNames singleSubFolder];
end
numberOfFolders = length(listOfFolderNames)
% Process all text files in those folders.
for k = 1 : numberOfFolders
% Get this folder and print it out.
thisFolder = listOfFolderNames{k};
fprintf('Processing folder %s\n', thisFolder);

% Get filenames of all TXT files.
filePattern = sprintf('%s/simass.txt', thisFolder);
baseFileNames = dir(filePattern);
numberOfFiles = length(baseFileNames);
% Now we have a list of all text files in this folder.

if numberOfFiles >= 1
    % Go through all those text files.
    for f = 1 : numberOfFiles
        fullFileName = fullfile(thisFolder, baseFileNames(f).name);
      fileID=fopen(fullFileName);
      c=textscan(fileID,'%s%s%s','Headerlines',10,'Collectoutput',true);
      fclose(fileID);
      %celldisp(c)   % display all cell values
      cellvalue=c{1}{2,3} 
      filePh = fopen('features.txt','w');
      fprintf(filePh,cellvalue);
      fclose(filePh);
        fprintf('     Processing text file %s\n', fullFileName);
    end
else
    fprintf('     Folder %s has no text files in it.\n', thisFolder);
end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the permission you use in `fopen`. From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html#input_argument_d119e316599):

> `'w'` - Open or create new file for writing. **Discard existing contents, if any.**

Which means you're discarding the contents every time, and you end up only having the last value. The fastest fix would be changing the permission to `'a'`, but I would suggest adding some changes to the code as follows:

1. Creating `cellvalue` before the loop, and read `c{1}{2,3}` into this new vector/cell array.
2. Perform the writing operation once, after `cellvalue` is fully populated.

```
cellvalue = cell(numberOfFiles,1);
for f = 1 : numberOfFiles
    ...
    cellvalue{f} = c{1}{2,3};
end
fopen(...);
fprintf(...);
fclose(...);
```

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry, the downside of free hosting... Not much I can do about it.

Comment: @am304 no worries, just giving you heads up